# Traverse cell values in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a table where data is stored in the format as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE TBL_COUNTING ( 
 DF_RECORD_STATUS NVARCHAR2(255), 
 SOURCE_FILE_NAME NVARCHAR2(255), 
 APP_HCP360_COUNT NUMBER, 
 STAGING_COUNT NUMBER, 
 SUPERCEEDED NUMBER );


SUPERCEEDED upload_trxn2015831_3039.csv      0                            2

TOTAL       upload_trxn2015831_3039.csv      2            2               0
```

I want to format the above in the format below. But I am unable to do so.

```
DF_RECORD_STATUS SOURCE_FILE_NAME            APP_HCP360_COUNT   STAGING_COUNT   SUPERCEEDED
SUPERCEEDED      upload_trxn2015831_3039.csv         2                            0
TOTAL            upload_trxn2015831_3039.csv         0            2               2
```

For far I was able to do the following:

```
SELECT 
DF_RECORD_STATUS,
SOURCE_FILE_NAME,
STAGING_COUNT,
CASE WHEN DF_RECORD_STATUS = 'NEW'
THEN
APP_HCP360_COUNT
ELSE
0
END AS APP_HCP360_COUNT,
SUPERCEEDED
FROM TBL_COUNTING 
WHERE SOURCE_FILE_NAME = 'upload_trxn2015831_3039.csv';
```

I have been trying to manipulate data using DF_RECORD_STATUS column but it is of no use.

Comment: can you provide a table creation script with datatypes and some sample data?

Comment: CREATE TABLE TBL_COUNTING
(
  DF_RECORD_STATUS  NVARCHAR2(255),
  SOURCE_FILE_NAME  NVARCHAR2(255),
  APP_HCP360_COUNT  NUMBER,
  STAGING_COUNT     NUMBER,
  SUPERCEEDED       NUMBER
)

Comment: what error do you get?  what is of 'no use'?

Comment: I do not get any errors, I am only unable to get the format as mentioned in my question. What I wanted to do was to traverse the value of column APP_HCP360_COUNT and SUPERCEEDED from the row where DF_RECORD_STATUS had value 'SUPERCEEDED' to the row where DF_RECORD_STATUS had value 'TOTAL'.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle LAG and LEAD analytics functions should do the job nicely. See the official documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions074.htm) or try this sample.  I'm still not quite clear on your data set but this should point you in the right direction:

```
   SELECT DF_RECORD_STATUS,
   SOURCE_FILE_NAME,
   STAGING_COUNT 
   LEAD(APP_HCP360_COUNT, 1) OVER (ORDER BY APP_HCP360_COUNT) AS "RecordCount" 
   FROM TBL_COUNTING 
   WHERE SOURCE_FILE_NAME = 'upload_trxn2015831_3039.csv';
```